# How do I create GUI classes for windows, which have subwindows/classes that can access to the main GUI's functions?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

How do I create GUI classes for windows which have subwindows/classes that can access the main GUI's functions?

I have the below code which modifies the compiled .ui code from designer. What I want it to do is, when clicking the top-right "X", or using File -> Exit function, to close the window comprising the Window_SecondWindow class, and show the main window again--effectively calling the main window's `show()` from the subclass. I want to show only one window at a time.

When the code is run as-is, the Window_SecondWindow class hides, but immediately shows again, leading me to believe `super` is acting as `self`.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from GUI import compiled_MainWindow
from GUI import compiled_SecondWindow

class Window_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = compiled_MainWindow.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.closeEvent = self.clicked_EXIT

        # connect widgets
        self.ui.Btn.clicked.connect(self.clicked_Btn)
        self.ui.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.clicked_EXIT)

        # add windows
        self.SecondWindow = SecondWindow()
        # more windows attached to main window

    def clicked_Btn(self):
        self.hide()
        self.SecondWindow.show()

    def clicked_EXIT(self):
        self.close()

class Window_SecondWindow(Window_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = compiled_SecondWindow.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.closeEvent = self.clicked_EXIT

        self.ui.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.clicked_EXIT)

    def clicked_EXIT(self):
        self.hide()
        super().show()
```

Comment: send main GUI as argument to subwindow - many GUIs send it as "parent" to every widget.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question, I'd like to address some important aspects.

1. First of all, **never** edit the generated code from pyuic to create your programs. They are intended to be used as imported modules, mostly as "resources": you import and integrate them into your code, but you should always leave them as they are. See the documentation on [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code) for more insight about this.
2. Be careful in overriding functions within the `__init__`: some functions are not "virtual" (thus, cannot be overwritten in such a way) and in some cases Qt always calls the base class function name anyway; just overwrite the method and call the base class implementation with super() if required. Also, `closeEvent` has the close *event* as a mandatory argument, and you **have** to add that to your overridden function, even if you don't use it (in the following examples I'm just using `*args`). That said, you should **never** use an overridden function as a slot that has a different argument, or viceversa.
3. Finally, you should not use capitalized names for attribute and variable names, as it is confusing and prone to errors (capitalization is mostly used for class names only, not their instancies).

### Now, the answer

You are almost right, `super()` acts "as self", in the sense that it just calls the inherited `show()` method of the class *against the instance*. So, it calls the show method of `Window_MainWindow`, but since the instance is the second window, it's the same as doing `Window_MainWindow.show(self)`, with `self` being the `Window_SecondWindow` *instance*; it is *exactly* as doing `self.show()`.

There are two (and a half) possibilities.

The first, more obvious solution, is to give a reference of the main window instance to the second one:

```
class Window_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.secondWindow = Window_SecondWindow()
        self.secondWindow.mainWindow = self

class Window_SecondWindow(Window_MainWindow):
    # ...
    def clicked_EXIT(self, *args):
        self.hide()
        self.mainWindow.show()
```

Be aware that while, as [@noras points out in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59584134/how-do-i-create-gui-classes-for-windows-which-have-subwindows-classes-that-can/59587881#comment105335339_59584134), you *could* set the main window as a parent in the init argument, but this only works as expected with QMainWindow and QDialog descendants; if the child widget is of any other kind, it will be shown *inside* the parent, not as a separate window.

The second (and more "Qt-wise correct") is to create a signal for the second class that is emitted when it's closed, and connect it in the main window so that it's shown again when that happens:

```
class Window_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.secondWindow = Window_SecondWindow()
        self.secondWindow.closed.connect(self.show)

class Window_SecondWindow(Window_MainWindow):
    closed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def clicked_EXIT(self, *args):
        self.hide()
        self.closed.emit()
```

The second-and-a-half solution is to use an [event filter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter):

```
class Window_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.secondWindow = Window_SecondWindow()
        self.secondWindow.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if source == self.secondWindow and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Close:
            self.show()
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Regarding point (1), I meant to convey pyuic5 generates my GUI code in python, then I import that and customize the result. The generated code remains unchanged, no need to make my life hard should I have to edit the GUI in designer. I managed to get the first method implemented.